# Is it valid to compare AICc among models with different numbers of independent vbls?

Tags: multiple-regression, aic

I am trying to interpret some results in a paper that presents AICc values for different candidate multiple regression models. The paper presents the model results broken down by numbers of independent vbls. I don't know a whole lot about AIC, so I'm wondering if it's valid to compare the AICc scores between, for instance, a 2-vbl and a 3vbl-model? The paper uses 4 vbls in total and presents an AICc score for models containing all possible subsets of these vbls. If this is not valid, would some other measure related to AICc (e.g. Akaike weights, etc.) be a valid comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be sort of the whole point of AIC. The answer to this can be found even on the  [wikipedia page for AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). I quote: "Given a set of candidate models for the data, the preferred model is the one with the minimum AIC value. Hence AIC not only rewards goodness of fit, but also includes a penalty that is an increasing function of the number of estimated parameters."

Whether AIC is a good criterion for the case at hand is another question, but you would need to provide more information to be able to answer that.